# How much do IDEs take advantage of multiple CPU cores?

Tags: cpu, multi-core, threads, hyper-threading, multi-threaded

So, how much do IDEs, for instance Android Studio or Eclipse, take advantage of multiple threads and CPU cores? That is, how much faster do they run on, say, a quad-core CPU compared with a dual-core CPU?

Comment: IDE's are generally single-task oriented.  So I would imagine it wouldn't make much difference.

Comment: The `make` systems that IDEs use to build projects might take advantage of multiple cores to compile a bunch of files in parallel.